# Bower Installation

Tags: node.js, bower

I am using a windows 8.1 maching,and trying to install the Bower automation tool via Git Bash. So what I found is this:

```
$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ npm install -g bower

$ which bower
>> /usr/local/bin/bower
```

However after typing the first command gitbash gives me this.

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program    Files\Git\usr\local'
at Error (native)
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: you do not have permission to create directory in C: program files folder

Comment: Can't I fix this by running git bash as an administrator?